# Unity running animations repeatedtly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D project with a stickman attached with hinge joints. I created this script and I am not really  familiar with Enumerators. I am trying to run an animation to make the player run while adding force. And for some reason the MoveLeft Enumerator keeps on running. I printed if it ran the function or the animation was on by default but it did in fact play it from the function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject leftLeg;
    public GameObject rightLeg;
    Rigidbody2D leftLegRB;
    Rigidbody2D rightLegRB;

    Animator anim;

    [SerializeField] float speed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] float jumpHeight = 2f;
    [SerializeField] float legWait = .5f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        leftLegRB = leftLeg.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rightLegRB = rightLeg.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        IEnumerator MoveRight(float seconds)
        {
            float endTime = Time.time + seconds;
            Debug.Log("Moved Right");

            while (Time.time < endTime)
            {
                leftLegRB.velocity = new Vector2(speed, leftLegRB.velocity.y);
                rightLegRB.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rightLegRB.velocity.y);
                yield return null;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator MoveLeft(float seconds)
        {
            float endTime = Time.time + seconds;
            Debug.Log("Moved Left");

            while (Time.time < endTime)
            {
                leftLegRB.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, leftLegRB.velocity.y);
                rightLegRB.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rightLegRB.velocity.y);
                yield return null;
            }
        }
        
        if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") != 0)
        {
            if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
            {
                anim.Play("Run");
                StartCoroutine(MoveRight(legWait));
            }
            else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
            {
                anim.Play("Run");
                StartCoroutine(MoveLeft(legWait));
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 0)
        {
            anim.Play("Idle");
        }
 
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            leftLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.up * (jumpHeight*1000));
            rightLegRB.AddForce(Vector2.up * (jumpHeight * 1000));
        }
    }
}
```

The idle animation keeps the legs at 0 but just doesn't work. No, it's not a key that stuck down. Their is also a balance script which selects the angle of the legs and torso but without the movement script it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You're starting coroutines, but never stopping them. In this block you should also call StopAllCoroutines (or save each routine into variable and stop them manually, that will be more convenient):

```
else if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 0)
    {
        anim.Play("Idle");
    }
```

But it's also a very strange way to animate and move character via leg rigidbodies... Maybe you should consider using a single Rigidbody for the character and a normal way to do animations, like using AnimationController and AnimationClips (they aren't that hard to understand and much more reliable than dealing with animation through physics).

Comment: OHHH well thanks, btw its like a stickman so each part is its each gameobject with its own RB and collider. OK well thanks. Also each leg has a balance script to choose my target rotation and thats how im aiming the leg. I think a normal type of animation would be too stiff since the thing with the target is pretty natural and adapts so sometimes it goes too far sometimes it barely moves. I want that kinda ragdolly effect like in gang beast if you know it.

Comment: So I tried it but it still doesn't stop. It keeps on registering the Moving left for no apparent reason. Is the GetAxis/GetAxisRaw part of the code the problem. I thought a computer followed instructions...

Comment: I think your gamepad maybe giving you non-zero input to the left over the dead zone. Just enter debug mode and check what input values you're getting.

Comment: okkkk i will use the console